# Wilfly 27 + Spring Boot 3.0.2 deploy errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deployment, wildfly

Looks like hibernate version ins't compatible with something in wildfly. It's my first time trying to deploy something in wildfly. I tried to change versions of my hibernate but still doesn't work

```
[2023-02-10 04:25:39,972] Artifact *-api:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
16:25:40,116 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "*-api.war" (runtime-name: "*-api.war")
16:25:51,493 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."*-api.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."*-api.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "*-api.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3924)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:73)
    ... 10 more

16:25:51,496 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "*-api.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"*-api.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"*-api.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"}}
16:25:51,497 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "*-api.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"*-api.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"*-api.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"}}
16:25:51,498 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "*-api.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"*-api.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"*-api.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"}}
16:25:51,829 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment *-api.war (runtime-name: *-api.war) in 331ms
[2023-02-10 04:25:51,907] Artifact *-api:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2023-02-10 04:25:51,907] Artifact *-api:war: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"*-api.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"*-api.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"}}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <name>***:: Api</name>
    <description>*:: Api</description>

    <artifactId>*-api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>17</source>
                        <target>17</target>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            --enable-preview
                        </compilerArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desenv</id>

            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" />
            <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.api" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.as.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />

            <module name="org.hibernate"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I tried deploy my spring boot 3 application with wildfly 27.0.1, but I'm getting this error

Comment: Spring boot 3 / Spring 6, does not work with javax packages due to changes of the same, so basically all dependencies that you have with javax, must be migrated to a newer version where it was replaced with jakarta.

Comment: yes, removing javax and replacing for jakarta worked for me. Thank you!